# Weird Ghettoblow Slapahoe Ubuntu Apt Signing Key

Tags: apt, security

I just downloaded a Ubuntu 18 ISO from the [Ubuntu site](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). I looked up the configured apt signing key (0x3B4FE6ACC0B21F32) on a [keyserver](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=0xC0B21F32&op=vindex) - entry shown below.

What's the deal with the Matthew Knight through Ghettoblow Slapahoe sigs starting 2018-03-25? Doesn't this mean the owner of the key signed those keys - or is this spoofable? If so why would the owner do that?

```
pub  4096R/C0B21F32 2012-05-11            
     Fingerprint=790B C727 7767 219C 42C8  6F93 3B4F E6AC C0B2 1F32 

uid Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
sig  sig3  C0B21F32 2012-05-11 __________ __________ [selfsig]
sig  sig   3F272F5B 2012-05-11 __________ __________ Ubuntu Archive Master Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
sig  sig   7D86500B 2012-05-11 __________ __________ Colin Watson <cjwatson@chiark.greenend.org.uk>
sig  sig   AB2A91F5 2012-05-11 __________ __________ James Troup <elmo@tasta.io>
sig  sig   01AA4A64 2012-05-19 __________ __________ Steve Langasek <vorlon@dodds.net>
sig  sig   3CBDCCE0 2012-12-08 __________ __________ []
sig  sig   1216648A 2014-10-31 __________ __________ Manfred Lichtenstern (DM8ANE) <dm8ane@darc.de>
sig  sig   46EB581F 2016-05-16 __________ __________ Stanislav Sidorenko (email&jabber) <mail@stanislavsidorenko.com>
sig  sig   D3745C02 2018-03-25 __________ __________ Matthew Knight <mkkongdonghard4u@gmail.com>
sig  sig   7967B697 2018-03-26 __________ __________ Matthew Knight (mattknight) <mkkongdonghard4@gmail.com>
sig  sig   D23D923A 2018-04-21 __________ __________ Ghetto D. Whipitgood (Ghetto-D Sales & Slangin' Ho, Inc.) <kokaine.candyman@gmail.com>
sig  sig   A4664187 2018-04-21 __________ __________ Pimp Tight MJG (Pimp Hard!) <mkdickhuge4u@gmail.com>
sig  sig   B7B66A8A 2018-04-21 __________ __________ Slim Shady (matt) <mkkongdonghard4@gmail.com>
sig  sig   B7B66A8A 2018-04-22 __________ __________ Slim Shady (matt) <mkkongdonghard4@gmail.com>
sig  sig   EB4F60BB 2018-04-23 __________ __________ Ghetto D. Whipitgood (Candy, Cream, or Rock... I Can Serve You On The Block.) <kocaine.candyman@gmail.com>
sig  sig   78CD7AAA 2018-04-25 __________ __________ Mihaardik Ifaapon Anpoonjab (mihaardik@mihaardik-minty-pc) <mihaardik.poonjab@hotmail.com>
sig  sig   E67A19F0 2018-04-25 __________ __________ Mihaardik Poonjab (midik@kocaine-mint-pc) <mihaardik.poonjab@hotmail.com>
sig  sig   FDCCABC5 2018-04-25 __________ __________ Ghetto D. Whipitgood (snowman) <kokaine.candyman@hotmail.com>
sig  sig   F3E8F3A1 2018-05-07 __________ __________ Ghettoblow Slapahoe (kocaine-kali-pc) <mkkongdonghard4u@gmail.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh oops. I misunderstood the meaning of the keyserver output. It means good ol
Ghettoblow Slapahoe has signed the ftpmaster@ubuntu.com key, not the other way around. Can all rest assured it is legit now G.Slapahoe has signed it ...

Curious there isn't more spam signings like this (maybe they are purged?).